# Monitoring a folder for a specific file

Tags: scripting, windows-explorer

I have a program that uploads .txt or .rje files from a folder. Now when you put any other file format into the folder, like .jar, then the application crashes.

Now I cannot change the mechanics of the application, so I would like to know if there is a type of program/script that I can use that monitors the folder for any files that are **non-txt/rje** and then move them out of the folder once they are put there...

Is this possible using a script? (I do not want to use a .exe application to do this...not allowed to install 3rd party software onto the server this folder exists...)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your solution won't work as you have a race condition between the program doing the upload and the one doing the deletion. If upload runs first it still crashes.

The correct solution is to modify the upload program to cope with this scenario.

If that is not possible then the only safe work around would be to use a new folder to drop the files in, have a script run that constantly scans the folder and if a new file appears either move it to the processing folder or deletes it as appropriate.

(For the actual detection that's not my area of expertise but the simplest would be to have a bat file that just runs periodically (or even just runs once and loops with a wait, check, move, wait, check, move, etc) and processes everything in the folder when it runs).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I hear what you say about the battle between the application and the script. I was just not sure if this could be done with a batch file